# NSUserDefaults and archiver retrieval issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsuserdefaults, nskeyedunarchiver

I encountered a strange problem with `NSArray`. The app requires to hit the same web service at two scenarios with different input. One is at initial state, where the response from server is saved to `NSUserDefaults` with the help of `NSKeyedArchiver`. And the next is while completing a particular action, then based on the response the stored value from `NSUserDefaults` is modified.

```
NSArray *sorted = [ActiveOrder arrayOfModelsFromDictionaries: [responseObject objectForKey:@"GetActiveOrdersResult"]]; //ActiveOrder is a custom JSON model object
NSSortDescriptor *orderCreateDate = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"orderCreateDate" ascending:YES];
ordersList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: [sorted sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:orderCreateDate, nil]]];

NSMutableArray *archiveArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:ordersList.count];
for (ActiveOrder *itemDetail in ordersList) {
    [archiveArray addObject:itemDetail];
} //if i log 'archiveArray' it prints valid value (array of 'ActiveOrder' objects)

NSData *itemDetailObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:archiveArray];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:itemDetailObject
                 forKey:TAG_ACTIVE_ORDERS_RESPONSE];
```

*When I try to unarchive the data stored earlier, it prints **@"6 objects"** instead of 6 ActiveOrder objects.*

```
NSMutableArray *itemsFromLastResult = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey: TAG_ACTIVE_ORDERS_RESPONSE]] mutableCopy];
```

I'm using the above line to access the stored value in order to modify. I'm so confused why it is printing @"6 objects" instead of actual objects. **And it is crashing randomly**(Guessing this could be the reason). Is there something I'm doing wrong with `NSKeyedArchiver`/`NSKeyedUnarchiver`

It would be great to know the solution. Thanks!

Comment: `NSUserDefaults` is not a general-purpose storage mechanism.  Use something else instead that doesn't involve `.plist` files.

Comment: Do you use encode / decode in your domain/actual objects' class?

Comment: @trojanfoe Thanks for the suggestion. I would give it a try. May I know the reason, going for one that doesn't involve plist?

Comment: @ondermerol I suppose yes. We modify some values manually at some point of function call. Is that it?

Comment: Not all objects can be stored within a `.plist` file, so you are better off writing the `NSData` objects resulting from serialization (i.e. KeyedArchiver) directly to disk.

Comment: Can you run this code: ActiveOrder *myObj = (ActiveOrder *)[itemsFromLastResult objectAtIndex:0];

Comment: @ondermerol after unarchiving?

Comment: It returns memory address 0x7be63b70 @ondermerol

Comment: @Nina, are you sure you implement coding protocol for your custom/actual domain class?  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/codingobjects.html

Answer (score 0):

NSUserDefaults save object, asynchronously!
Try
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
After setObjectForKey

Comment: Isn't using synchronize discouraged? And i tried it, no change.